# Why is the ArrayList import not working? (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, import

The following code will not compile, apparently because "the import conflicts with a type defined in the same file." Why won't this work?!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

}
}
```

Comment: because you import ArrayList and then try to make a class called ArrayList. It's just what the warning says...

Answer (score 5):

Just rename your class to something else, like MyArrayList

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is defined in java.util.ArrayList. The error message is telling you that your class name is conflicting with that definition.

This won't do anything except create a list, but this will fix your compilation problem..

```
public class MyListTest { //  <---- This line cannot say "public class ArrayList"
   public static void main(String [] args) {
      ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   }
}
```